# Upstart causes kernel panic on embedded Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, boot, upstart

I am using `ptxdist` to create kernel and rootfs images for a Linux embedded system, running on an ARM Cortex A8 CPU.

I was trying to use a newer compiler (GCC 5+) and so was forced to upgrade several external packages that would not compile under the new GCC.

I compiled the following versions of Upstart and its immediate dependencies:

```
upstart: 1.13.2  
libnih: 1.0.3  
dbus: 1.11.2  
json-c: 0.12.1
```

When I boot, I get the following message:

```
init: com.ubuntu.Upstart.c:3525: Assertion failed in control_emit_event_emitted: env != NULL
init: Caught abort, core dumped
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000600
```

Searching online did not yield useful hints - [the only relevant issue I found is this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/upstart/+bug/1161329/), but it is relevant to an older version of Upstart, and my libnih is of the correct version already.

Comment: Maybe it will be useful for somebody in 2022, I have tried to compile latest upstart (1.13.2) for an embedded device with the latest libnih (1.0.3-ubuntu27) and without success with the same assertion. But, why I tried to use the latest version instead of 1.8 (which is worked). Because upstart-udev-bridge not working in 1.8 with kernel 5.
After some time I found the reason, upstart-udev-bridge.conf need to be edited as 'start on started udev' and everything will work, bridge started too early in default conf. So 1.8 works normally, 1.13.2 not

Comment: Bug described here
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-manta/+bug/1412543

Answer (score 2):

According to comment #8 in the bug report you linked, it is not enough to use version 1.0.3 of libnih -- you have to specifically use the Ubuntu version, as this seems to include dbus fixes which could solve the problem you are seeing. From the bug report:

> **David Ireland (e-david)** wrote on 2013-04-22:  #7
>
> I've built libnih
>   1.0.3 from source and also made sure that upstart builds with that version of the nih-dbus-tool. I'm still having this problem.
>
> **James Hunt (jamesodhunt)** wrote on 2013-04-22: #8
>
> Which problem? The
>   crash? If so, you are still using the wrong version of libnih: you
>   should be using the Ubuntu version (specifically 1.0.3-4ubuntu16) from
>   here:
>   https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/raring/libnih/raring
>
> You do not need the --session flag to run a "Session Init" (yes, this
>   is a little confusing but --session was added for testing a long time
>   ago and is still required for that). A "Session Init" only requires
>   "--user".